# Creating angularjs directive with id attribute for internal html but id still on outer html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

So I have created this checkbox directive that is made up of a label and input element.
I want to set an id attribute on the directive and set this as the "id" of the input element and the label "for" attribute. This works fine, but the problem is that it remains on the outer html which is a div, so it breaks my directive. I thought that if you had the directive set to replace : true, then this would remove the html that defined the directive .

The directive is as follows

```
angular.module('journal.directives', []).
  directive('fancyCheckbox', function(){
  return {
    restrict : 'EA', 
    replace : true,
    template : '<div class="fancyCheckbox">' +
           '<input type="checkbox" id="{{ id }}" />' +
           '<label for="{{ id }}" ></label>' +
           '</div>',
    scope : {
      colour : '@',
      id : '@', 
    },
    link : function(scope, elem, attrs){
      var spotColourClass;
      var valid_colours = ['blue', 'green', 'gray', 'purple', 
              'blue', 'orange', 'charcoal', 'light',
                  'yellow', 'red'];

      if(valid_colours.indexOf(scope.colour) !== -1){                   
      spotColourClass = scope.colour + "spot";
      }else{
        spotColourClass = 'greenspot';
      }

    elem.addClass(spotColourClass);
    }
  };
});
```

When I call my directive as

```
<fancy-checkbox colour="red" id="mycheckbox"></fancy-checkbox>
```

and it becomes

```
<div class="fancyCheckbox ng-isolate-scope greenspot" colour="green" id="mycheckbox">
  <input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox">
  <label for="mycheckbox"></label>
</div>
```

You see that the "id" is still on the outer div, which is not what I want. I assumed that this would be removed. So do I just have to remove it manually in the linking function

Hope someone can help

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [Angular directive guide](http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.8/docs/guide/directive):

> The replacement process migrates all of the attributes / classes from the old element to the new one.

So, what you're seeing is expected behavior.

Rather than remove the attribute in link I'd just create a new attribute, for instance `check-id` and use it like this:

```
<fancy-checkbox colour="red" check-id="mycheckbox"></fancy-checkbox>
```

add it to your scope:

```
checkId : '@',
```

and use that within your template:

```
template : '<div class="fancyCheckbox">' +
       '<input type="checkbox" id="{{ checkId }}" />' +
       '<label for="{{ checkId }}" ></label>' +
       '</div>',
```

[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dLLan/1/)

Comment: Yeah thanks, that's great. Maybe I need to read the docs more.

Comment: With your solution the input and the div element both have their id set to mycheckbox. Shouldn't element IDs be unique within the entire document? Maybe, one should append someting to the id of the input tag, like this: 'id="{{ checkId }}chk' just to make it unique.

Comment: @zszep: with replace: true, the original element is going to be replaced with the template. so, in the final html only one element would exist with that specific id